# How To Place List<LatLng> as Markers On Map in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Can anyone tel me how to place List LatLng On map,instead of placing invidual LatLng On Map,By calling MarkOnMap() inside foreach/for loop.
Following is my code

```
             foreach (var marker in markerArray)
             {
                MarkOnMap(new LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(marker.location.latitude), Convert.ToDouble(marker.location.longitude)), marker.displayText, vehicleMarkerIcon);
              }


Marker MarkOnMap(LatLng markerLatLng,string timeStamp, int  markericon)

        {
        Marker markerObj = null;
        this.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
        try
        {
          var marker = new MarkerOptions();

     marker.SetPosition(markerLatLng);
   marker.SetTitle(timeStamp);                 
         marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBitmap(markericon));
                marker.Anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
                markerObj = map.AddMarker(marker);
            }
            catch (Java.Lang.Exception ex)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        });

        return markerObj;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)), you could only use `AddMarker()` to add a marker to the map once a time. So you have to use foreach/for loop to add a list of markers.